# Angular cancel button is not working as expected

Tags: html, angular

Hello I have a button that is working fine before, but after some updates of some of the devs I'm having a hard time debugging the button. I am new to angular and I will need some help in making it work.

[image]

here when i have a multilingual language the configure now button will appear

[image]

then in this page I'm having the back and cancel button, but upon clicking both of them none of them works.

Here is the current implementation

```
<div class="language-translation-container">
  <div class="language-translation-section">
    <div class="language-translation-header">
      <div class="arrow-back-icon"  
        (click)="cancelSave()">
      </div>
      <div class="language-translation-title">
        {{ 'create_master_bot.master_bot_info.create_masterbot' | translate }}
      </div>
    </div>

    <translation-config
      #translationForm
      (saveTranslationData)="saveConfig($event)"
      (saveDetectionData)="saveConfig($event)"
    ></translation-config>
  </div>

  <div class="language-translation-section">
    <div class="bot-image-placeholder">
      <div class="botbox-icon"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="button-container">
  <div class="button">
    <caip-converse-button
      [val]="'create_master_bot.master_bot_info.cancel' | translate"
      [buttonType]="'secondary'"
      (click)="cancelSave()"
    ></caip-converse-button>
  </div>

  <div class="button">
    <caip-converse-button
      [val]="'create_master_bot.master_bot_info.create' | translate"
      [buttonType]="'primary'"
      (click)="translationForm.saveConfig()"
    ></caip-converse-button>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is the function of the cancelsave

```
cancelSave(): void {
  this.translationConfig.emit(false);
  this.translationForm.cancelSave(false);
  this.toastr.warning(
    this.getTranslation('translation-config.language_translator_not_saved'),
    this.warningMsg
  );
}
```

this is the masterbot/parent

```
<master-bot-form
    class="master-bot-form"
    [showCancelButton]="changeCancelButton"
    (showLanguageConfig)="showLanguageConfig = true"
    (nextPage)="goToNext($event)"
    (masterBotInfo)="masterBotInfo = $event"
    (cancelCreateBot)="cancelCreateBot.emit(true)"
    [disableCreateButton]="disableCreateButton"
  ></master-bot-form>
```

```
saveTranslationConfig(config) {
  if (config.alwaysDetectLanguage === undefined) {
    this.saveDetectionConfig(config);
  } else {
    this.translationConfig = config ? config : {};
    this.showLanguageConfig = false;
  }
}
```

i tried to emit true or just add a config that has empty value to be passed on the cancel button, and i expect the button to go back to the previous popup when i click the cancel/ back button